# Why do constructor calls in C++ and Java require explicit type parameters?

Tags: java, c++, parametric-polymorphism

C++ and Java have this similarity in how they handle parametric polymorphism: both will infer the type parameters to regular functions or methods, but require the programmer to explicitly give the type parameters when calling a constructor (Though this was changed in Java 7).

What is the technical reason behind this behavior?

**edit**: I mistakenly thought this applied to Scala as well.
Here is an example from Java:

```
class Foo<T> {
    Foo(T x) { }
}

<T> void foo(T x) { }


Foo<Integer> f = new Foo(3);
foo(3);
```

both of these are legal, but the first one creates a "raw type" rather than a `Foo<Integer>`, and performs an unchecked assignment.

Comment: I didn't quite follow that - can you provide an example? Specifically what you mean by '...explicitly give the type parameters when calling...'

Comment: Scala will infer type parameters in constructor calls, e.g. `class C[T]; val c: C[Int] = new C` or `class C[T]; def foo(c: C[Int]) { }; foo(new C)`

Comment: @MikeD OK, I gave an example from Java.

Comment: @SethTisue Yes, thank you; I got confused because Scala requires an explicit type when making an anonymous subclass (which really has nothing to do with it being a constructor).

Comment: The first *what* creates a "raw type"? The problem is that you aren't parameterizing the `new Foo(3);` call, and the Java compiler will infer the type if you use the diamond.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, that's Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because C++ templates can be specialized.

That means that just because there's a main definition:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    Foo(T x) { }
};
```

and clearly `int` will be accepted by `Foo<int>(int)`, it's completely possible that there's also a specialized definition

```
template<>
class Foo<Foobar>
{
    Foo(int x) { }
};
```

which also accepts an `int` parameter.

Add user-defined type conversions to the mix, and you see that it just isn't possible to figure out the class's type parameters from function arguments.

And in fact, inference of type parameters for constructors IS allowed.  But not inference of  the class template parameters.  For example, allowing implicit upcast when constructing a smart pointer:

```
template<typename T>
class a_smart_ptr
{
    template<typename TOther>
    a_smart_ptr(TOther* p) { }
};
```